# Google Fit API not returning activities from last 90 days

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm trying to retrieve the Google Fit activities from the last 90 days, but it is not returning all the activities.

This is the date range:

- Start date = today - 90 days = Nov/09/2021 00:00:00
- End date = today = Feb/07/2022 00:00:00

Today I inserted some activities in Nov/09/2021, but the API is not retrieving them. Is there any limit to the time range? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Code sample:

```
final DataReadRequest req = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

Fitness.getHistoryClient(mContext, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(mContext))
        .readData(req)
        .addOnSuccessListener(dataReadResponse -> {
            if (dataReadResponse.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // read response data
            }
        });
```

EDIT: Apparently `setTimeRange` filters by the activity creation date, not the date I set in Google Fit. I did a test with an account that had activities at November 09 (inserted in the past on that day) and they were returned by the API.

Comment: Your start date is after your end date.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, I messed up when creating the question, but in the original code it was in the correct order. I updated the question now. Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to read sessions, why not use [`SessionReadRequest`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/SessionReadRequest)?